# Batch request returns undefined

Tags: web3js, aws

I'm trying to get batch requests to work with an Amazon Managed Blockchain, so I set up a simple test.

The error I get is `Invalid JSON RPC response: {}`.

This returns `undefined` if I don't log the error;

```
const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();

    batch.add(
        web3.eth.getBalance.request(
            '0xf2D2079dF0ad7a4E0675Cb343981B77c71Ce29e4',
            'latest',
            function (error, balance) {
                console.log(balance);
            }
        )
    );

    batch.add(
        web3.eth.getBalance.request(
            '0xFe44DAeb65166846fccb3f4aA7186e36247b1C1E',
            'latest',
            function (error, balance) {
                console.log(balance);
            }
        )
    );

    batch.execute();
```

While the same code outside of a batch request works just fine:

```
    web3.eth.getBalance(
        '0xFe44DAeb65166846fccb3f4aA7186e36247b1C1E',
        'latest',
        function (error, balance) {
            console.log(balance);
        }
    );
```

I'm running the latest version of web3.

EDIT:

This seems to happen with Amazon Managed Blockchain for some reason, but not with Infura.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Amazon Managed Blockchain [does not support batch requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/ethereum-dev/ethereum-json-rpc.html#supported-json-rpc).